# write vertical text using DrawString

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawing

I want to write a vertical text in my graphic instances using **DrawString**.

My code is like this :

```
var graph = Graphics.FromImage(map);
```

And I  read the text and their position from Database :

```
graph.DrawString(ObjStationRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == t.StationId).First().Description, new Font("B Nazanin", 18), Brushes.White, t.XLocation + 70, t.YLocation +80);
```

But my problem is ,i need to write the text in vertical position not horizontal .But **DrawString** write the text in horizontal !!

Best regards

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use

```
System.Drawing.StringFormat drawFormat = new System.Drawing.StringFormat();
drawFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;
```

and add it as the last param to `DrawString`

Comment: Yes  i want to that but i have to wait for 12 min:)